# When i install selenium i met this error "subprocess-exited-with-error", error log below. How can I fix it, Thanks

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [24 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "D:\MSYS\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "D:\MSYS\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "D:\MSYS\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\hunhat\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dlmfrauw\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 355, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "C:\Users\hunhat\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dlmfrauw\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\hunhat\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dlmfrauw\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 126, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 105, in uses_msvc
        File "C:\Users\hunhat\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dlmfrauw\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\config.py", line 223, in try_compile
          self._compile(body, headers, include_dirs, lang)
        File "C:\Users\hunhat\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dlmfrauw\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\config.py", line 128, in _compile
          self.compiler.compile([src], include_dirs=include_dirs)
        File "C:\Users\hunhat\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dlmfrauw\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 343, in compile
          self.initialize()
        File "C:\Users\hunhat\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dlmfrauw\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 246, in initialize
          raise DistutilsPlatformError(
      distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: --plat-name must be one of ('win32', 'win-amd64', 'win-arm32', 'win-arm64')
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I have upgraded python version 23.2.1, but It still doesn't work